# Passing Env Variables to Docker For Create React App

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I want to pass a URL variable that my react app will require.
Some of the things I've tried:

- Passing it in my run script

```
docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    -e REACT_APP_ENV=production \
    -v ${PWD}:/app \
    -v /app/node_modules \
    -p 3002:3000 \
    -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true \
    chronicle-frontend:dev
```

- I've tried adding the variables to my Dockerfile

```
#pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_API http://localhost:4000/graphql
ENV REACT_APP_ENV development

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# Exposed for other containers
EXPOSE 3000

# start app
# CMD ["npm", "run", "start-dev", "-p", "3003"]
CMD yarn start -p 3000
```

I've read a few things that say `process.env` should be accessible in the react front end but that hasn't been my experience recently.

```
 Line 12:14:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  10 | 
  11 | const link = createHttpLink({
> 12 |   if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV == "development"){
     |              ^
  13 |     uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_API
  14 |   } else {
  15 |     uri: 'backend:3001/graphql'
```

Does react have a dot-env ? I've tried env-cmd, didn't work.

Comment: What bundler are you using? Most should allow you to use environment variables in your code, and they are replaced with the value at build time.

Comment: without docker I get the same thing if I run this `REACT_APP_ENV=development yarn start` or `REACT_APP_ENV=development npm start` gives me the same response. Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I was asking what bundler you were using, but assuming you're using create-react-app, you're using Webpack. It looks like that's a syntax error on the client side, so maybe check if your syntax is completely correct? (Doesn't seem like it should ask you to replace a period with a comma).

Comment: Yeah seems like some syntax error from client-side.

Comment: My last comment wasn't directed to anyone. Yeah it was just a syntax error, thanks.